# Непонятное задание по формуле x(n+1)=a*x(n)+b(mod127)

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Задали написать программу,.. условие-то есть, но какое-то для меня оно плохопонимаемое. Вот оно:

> Пусть некоторое устройство содержит в качестве состояния число от 0 до 126. В каждый следующий момент времени число меняется по формуле x(n+1)=a*x(n)+b(mod127), где а=10, b=11. Создать класс, отображающий это устройство.
>
> В классе должны быть функции-члены:
>
> - конструктор, имеющий аргумент – начальное состояние,
> - функция, переводящая устройство в следующее состояние,
> - функция, выводящая на экран состояние устройства.

Решил задачу, думаете написал то, о чем меня просят?
Вот код:

```
// List.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "windows.h"

using namespace std;

class device {
public:
    int num;        // то что содержит 0->126

    device();        // Конструктор

    void form();
    void Print();

};

device::device()        // 1 констр-р с нач. знач num
{
    cout << "Vvedi svoe znachenie: ";
    cin >> num;
}

void device::form()        // 2 перевод устр. в след. сост.
{
    this->num = (10 * this->num + 11) % 127;
}

void device::Print(void)    // 3 вывод на экран
{
    cout << this->num << '\n';
}

void main(void)
{
    // Создаем объект first класса device
    device first;
    first.form();
    first.Print();
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x(n+1) - это следующее состояние. оно считается в методе form(). x(n) соответственно текущее.

x(n+1)=a*x(n)+b(mod127), где а=10, b=11.
в num хранится текущее состояние. то есть в методе form() пишем формулу из условия, заменяя х на num. примерно так:

num=a*num+b....

здесь в правой части вы используете текущее значение, затем по выполнении всех операций вместо текущего записывается следующее. (которое при след. вызове функции будет уже текущим)